# Adding tail to snake game [c++ sfml]

Tags: c++, sfml

I want to move the snake's tail by filling the gap it creates each time the head moves:
.**o**oox
.ooo x
. oo**o**x
So basically the last element moves into the gap. I can get the position of gap and create a tail there but as soon as I have more than 1 tail object it doesn't work correct. I believe it creates the new tail object on the same position as other tails, so the gap. Tail = rep

For tail

```
    //If tail exists
    if(imamoRep)
    {
            rep[repCount-1].setPosition(gap);

            temp[0] = rep[repCount-1]; //Remember last element
            for(int i=1;i<repCount;i++)
            {
                rep[i] = rep[i-1];
            }
            rep[0]=temp[0];   //assign last element to first
    }
```

Drawing

```
for(int i=0; i<repCount; i++)
    {
        window.draw(rep[i]);
    }
```

I'm guessing I did something wrong with arrays, the last element should become first and all others should move to left, so there's a new last tail. I created 100 tail elements in the beggining so I only need to draw them correctly. If I remove the tail code except the first line that sets position then I get this result: [image]

Tails are left behind, because only the position of last element changes, otherwise as said before all tails are on the same position. I would really appriciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. Think of what this loop is doing to your positions:

```
for(int i = 1; i < repCount; ++i)
{
    rep[i] = rep[i - 1];
}
```

Starting at `i=1` it'll assign `rep[1]` the value of `rep[0]`. Next for `i=2` it'll assign `rep[2]` the value of `rep[1]` which was overwritten with `rep[0]` on the previous iteration. And so on...

What you need to do is invert the loop writing the element at `i+1` before writing the element at `i`:

```
for(int i = repCount - 1; i > 0; --i)
{
    rep[i] = rep[i - 1];
}
```

Note that [std::copy_backward](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward) generically implements this behaviour. I.e. you can rewrite the loop above as:

```
if(repCount > 0)
{
    // Assuming rep is a std::vector using std::vector::begin
    std::copy_backward(rep.begin(), rep.begin() + repCount - 1, rep.begin() + repCount);
}
```

Comment: I think the array works ok now, but the same problem is still present, all my tails are always on the same position (on top of each other), I've been looking at my code for quite a while, but I can't see why.

Comment: Nevermind, fixed my own problem, should've put the code for tail inside the time elapsed if statement, so it renenders every 0.1 seconds just like the head and not every frame, thanks again for helping me with arrays.